# Price Calculation Formulas for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce, and also I'm using a free plugin, "**Product Options and Price Calculation Formulas for WooCommerce – Uni CPO**".

I'm having a little trouble there. My website sells a product using **meter per square**, so if my client want one meter I use this formula to calculate the price:

```
{uni_cpo_metrosquadrados2}x30.25
```

From here, everything is fine. Now my question is: My product has **1.778 meters per square** per box. How is it possible to adjust **(round up)** the client meters to my box?

So, for example, imagine that the client wants one meter, but he needs to buy a box because a box has 1.778 meters, and he can't buy only one meter. I want to round up every time my client sets some value. Like, if he wants two meters, he needs to buy two boxes.

Comment: Please clarify what "meter per square" means - I assuming that's a transliteration from Spanish or Portuguese? If it's a unit of 2D area then the term in English is ["square metres"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_metre) though you might come across people saying "meters-squared" (though strictly-speaking, "meters squared" [means something else](https://www.mrsphysics.co.uk/blog/difference-between-square-metres-and-metres-squared/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
(ceil(({uni_cpo_meters}/1.778))*your price
```

This will round up the number.

Comment: As for the downvote, it's possible that they didn't see this as on topic for Stack Overflow, since it relates to how to use a third-party plugin, and wasn't clearly a programming question? Regardless, this looks like a good solution, given the availability of a `ceil()` function.

Comment: @JeremyCaney `ceil()` has been in PHP for 21 years...since PHP4. So this is fine - though I'd add whitespace for readability.